# Updating mysql database when data is passed through as sessions

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

I've got the sessions working to display the child information, I now want to be able to edit that information and update the database. I've tried every youtube video and website but nothing uses $_SESSION they all use $_POST.

```
<div class="post">
  <h1 class="title">Child Details: </h1>
    <p class="title"><img src=" <?php echo "".$_SESSION['sourcepath']; ?>" 
    </p>
    <p class="title"><?php echo "".$_SESSION['ChildID']; ?></p>

    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 106px">Name</td>
            <td style="width: 252px"><?php       echo "".$_SESSION            ['Firstname']; ?> <?php echo "".$_SESSION['Surname']; ?></td>
            <td style="width: 94px">School</td>
            <td><form method="post">
                <br />
                <textarea name="School" cols="20" rows="5"><?php echo "".$_SESSION['School']; ?></textarea></form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 106px">Date of Birth</td>
            <td><?php echo "".$_SESSION['DateOfBirth']; ?></td>
            <td style="width: 94px">English</td>
            <td><form method="post">
                <br />
                <textarea name="English" cols="20" rows="5"><?php echo "".$_SESSION['English']; ?></textarea></form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 106px">Age</td>
            <td><?php echo "".$_SESSION['Age']; ?>;</td>
            <td style="width: 94px">Science</td>
            <td><form method="post">
                <br />
                <textarea name="Science" cols="20" rows="5"><?php echo "".$_SESSION['Science']; ?></textarea></form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 106px">Address</td>
            <td><form method="post">
                <br />
                <textarea name="Address" cols="20" style="height: 89px"><?php echo "".$_SESSION['Address']; ?></textarea></form>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 94px">Maths</td>
            <td><form method="post">
                <br />
                <textarea name="Maths" cols="20" rows="5"><?php echo "".$_SESSION['Maths']; ?></textarea></form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 106px">Postcode:</td>
            <td><?php echo "".$_SESSION['PostCode']; ?>;</td>
            <td style="width: 94px">Homework</td>
            <td><form method="post">
                <br />
                <textarea name="Homework" cols="20" rows="5"><?php echo "".$_SESSION['Homework']; ?></textarea></form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 106px">Contact Number</td>
            <td><form method="post">
                <textarea name="ContactNumber" cols="20" rows="2"><?php echo "".$_SESSION['ContactNumber']; ?></textarea></form>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 94px">Additional</td>
            <td><form method="post">
                <br />
                <textarea name="Additional" cols="20" rows="8"><?php echo "".$_SESSION['Additional']; ?></textarea></form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 106px">Mother Name</td>
            <td><?php echo "".$_SESSION['MotherName']; ?></td>
            <td style="width: 94px">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 106px">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 94px">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 106px">Last Update</td>
            <td><?php echo "".$_SESSION['TimeStamp']; ?></td>
            <td style="width: 94px">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 106px">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td style="width: 94px">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 106px">



            </td>
            <td>
            <form method="post" action="updatetest.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['ChildID']; ?>"/>
                <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Update" /></form>
            </td>







<?php session_start(); ?>
    <?php       
    $connect = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1" , "root" , "") or die ("Couldnt connect     to            database");
    mysql_select_db("travellerfile") or die ("couldnt find the database");

    $School = $_SESSION['School'];
    $Maths = $_SESSION['Maths'];
    $English = $_SESSION['English'];
    $Science = $_SESSION['Science'];
    $Homework = $_SESSION['Homework'];
    $Additional = $_SESSION['Additional'];
    $id = $_SESSION['ChildID'];

    $q = "SELECT * FROM child WHERE ChildID = $_SESSION[ChildID]";
    $result = mysql_query($q);
    $person = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $u = "UPDATE child SET Maths= '$_SESSION['Maths']', Science= '$_SESSION['Science']';
?>
```

Comment: Updating a row using a session, is similar to updating a row, by any value

Comment: so what would the code be? i've tried everything and nothing works.

Comment: you are not running the update query `$u`

Comment: 1st - PHP code must always be before your HTML code...
2nd - Don't use SESSION for UPDATES and etc.. Use POST for that...

Comment: @Svetlio That technically isn't true at all, it all depends on the structure of your logic and other factors.

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SESSION['School'] = $_POST['School'];
$School = $_SESSION['School'];
```

Somewhere you'll have to declare that $_SESSION['School'] contains the value of the Textarea with the name 'School'. You can't just expect PHP to put POST variables into SESSION variables

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
  $_SESSION['ChildID'] = 5;

 <form method="post" action="updatetest.php">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['ChildID']; ?>"/>
 <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Update" /></form>
```

This will post you:

```
 $_POST['id'] = 5;
```

So:

```
 UPDATE table SET col = $_POST['id'];
```

Comment: This is more or less what i was going to post. If you want to edit the data, you'll be to put it into a form and then use POST or GET to pass the updated data and then you can use PHP to collect the data before updating the record.

Answer (score 0):

Update `$_SESSION` end grab `$_POST` for database;

```
...
$School = $_['School'] = $_POST['School'];
$Maths = $_SESSION['Maths'] = $_POST['Maths'];
$English = $_SESSION['English'] = $_POST['English'];
$Science = $_SESSION['Science'] = $_POST['Science'];
$Homework = $_SESSION['Homework'] = $_POST['Homework'];
$Additional = $_SESSION['Additional'] = $_POST['Additional'];
$id = $_SESSION['ChildID'];
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `$_POST` and `$_SESSION` are merely arrays.  The only thing that makes them special is that they are global.  So, if you have code that works for `$_POST`, just substitute in the corresponding `$_SESSION` values.

What your real issue is, is that you are submitting a form. Forms can submit using `get` or `post` methods. There is no `session` method.  So your values are arriving at your php script in the `$_POST` variable.  You could then copy them to the `$_SESSION` variable before running your update, but there's really no good reason to. The only reason they would need to be in `$_SESSION` is so that they can be output if the form needs to be re-displayed with the submitted values.